# After editing user details, should the user stay on the same page or return to Settings?

Tags: navigation, edit, usability

Scenario: An administrator user is on a page with a table of all the users on the platform and can click a username to edit the user's details. If the administrator is creating a new user and then saves that new user, it makes sense to return the administrator the users table so they can keep creating new users. If the administrator is editing an existing user and then saves those changes, should they remain on the Edit User page rather than being redirected to the Users table? What use cases are there for remaining on the Edit User page vs. redirecting back to the users table?

I anticipate that once a new user is activated, the administrator doesn't need to make further changes. When editing a user, an administrator might save the page after each edit and want to make more edits after saving.